# Spring MVC portlet in Liferay 6.2, Model properties are null upon form post

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I've tried to clone a Spring MVC Portlet project but upon posting the form `todo` properties are all null.

Repo is available on [Github](https://github.com/jzinedine/try_git/tree/master/reference/java/spring-porlet-mvc/spring3-portlet).

Here is the Controller code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class ToDoListController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String view() {
        return "list";
    }

    @ActionMapping
    public void save(@Valid ToDo toDo, BindingResult result, @CookieValue("JSESSIONID") String jsessionid, 
            PortletSession session, ModelMap modelMap) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            // could use entityManager to persist; put in session for this example
            List<ToDo> toDos = (List<ToDo>) session.getAttribute("toDos");
            if (toDos == null) {
                toDos = new ArrayList<ToDo>();
            }
            toDos.add(toDo);
            session.setAttribute("toDos", toDos);

            modelMap.put("msg", String.format("You added a TODO: %s", toDo.getTitle()));
        }
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    private ToDo loadModel() {
        return new ToDo();
    }
}
```

Here is the View:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:if test="${msg ne null}">
    <div class="portlet-msg-success"><c:out value="${msg}" /></div>
</c:if>

<portlet:actionURL var="save" />

<form:form modelAttribute="toDo" action="${save}" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a TODO</legend>
        <div>
            <form:label path="title" cssStyle="display:block">Title:</form:label>
            <form:input path="title" />
            <form:errors path="title" cssClass="portlet-msg-error" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="due" cssStyle="display:block">Due (MM/DD/YYYY):</form:label>
            <form:input path="due" />
            <form:errors path="due" cssClass="portlet-msg-error" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="description" cssStyle="display:block">Description:</form:label>
            <form:textarea path="description" />
            <form:errors path="description" cssClass="portlet-msg-error" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

And here is the Context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="webBindingInitializer">
            <bean id="configurableWebBindingInitializer"
                class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
                <property name="validator">
                    <ref bean="validator" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

=====================================================================
***Update:***

Here is the working version: https://github.com/jzinedine/FirstPortlet

Comment: I had some similar issues. Which LR version are you using, is it 6.1GA2? Check your `web.xml` in the *deployed* webapps (the new LR version messes up the `ContextLoaderListeners`). Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739905/liferay-spring-spring-web-mvc-autowired-dont-work

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Liferay 6.2.0GA1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>` in your liferay-portlet.xml when using Spring MVC with Liferay 6.2. It is explained on Liferay 6.2 documentation at the end of this [page](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/passing-info-from-action-to-render-phase-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en).

Comment: I've created a new maven based portlet from scratch and by adding the mentioned tag, problem get resolved, thanks for your help, I'll push the working version to Github and update the question.